# Caching a SOAP web service in a local mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, soap

I am retrieving multiple soap xml files (from the same server) and have created a simple php application to display, search and add to cart listings from the soap xml data.

There is a lot of data and even if I restrict it, it is still too slow in response time to use effectively for getting and setting data live ( 10 seconds+ )

So, I am thinking about taking each of the relevant soap feeds and automatically adding the data each day to a mysql database. Then just working directly with the database. At the point of submitting the order, I will update the relevant order data within the soap web service.

Is this the correct approach? Are there any alternatives? How can this auto update of the database be performed?

Answer (score 0):

You'll generate a mirror of the web service. With advantages (better performance) and disadvantages (not live data). If you ask me, **I would not do that** as it defeats the principals of a service oriented environment.

If you want to cache responses of the SOAP server, a HTTP proxy between you and the SOAP server would be the most transparent approach. It will cache responses but your application still thinks it is live data (and can kept unchanged)

Also I would try to speed up the SOAP communication. For example you could send multiple requests simultaneously using techniques like the `socket_select()` approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, makes sense. Will have a look into the http proxy / caching and socket_select approach.

Comment: @MartynLee Ok, good luck :)! You can drop a comment if you need help.

Comment: I am struggling a bit actually to find a suitable example of how to set up the HTTP proxy. Can you point me in the right direction? Or perhaps instead of this, could I just retrieve previous orders and the product list and store in a php session? then just deal directly with that

Comment: @MartynLee Which proxy do you use?

Comment: I don't have one in place, I just been struggling trying to find an example of how to set one up. It is not something I have experience with. That's why I wondered if I could just use php sessions instead. What do you think?

Comment: Of course 'you can' do it. Its your decision :). It will work.